# github webhook fails to connect to jenkins with public ip

Tags: docker, jenkins, github

I am trying to configure github webhooks with my jenkins server but I keep getting "failed to connect". Note that I am using a **public ip** and not a private or localhost address, At first, icmp protocol was blocked on my firewall but even after allowing it, it still doesn't work.

However, when I proxy my server (using smee client) and use the proxied url in the webhook instead, it works fine, so I thought the problem was jenkins url (in system configuration of jenkins) so I changed that to the public ip but it doesn't have any effect, now I'm clueless.

It might be relevant to mention that jenkins is running on a docker container,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the webhook must pass through a web server and not to jenkins directly, So I configured nginx as a reverse proxy to jenkins server and it worked fine.